# Push notification using GCM which key should I create?

Tags: android, push-notification, key, google-cloud-messaging

Hi android developers,

Today I have decided to use Push notification of GCM. But getting stuck with creating key.
Steps I followed below steps provided in [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

1. Created project.
2. under API & Auth Google Cloud Messaging for android turned ON
3. Here I stuck, which key to choose. In docs it clearly says to select server key but in [api key help doc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys) says:
   *A.Create and use a **server key** if your application runs on a server.* 
   *B. Create and use an **Android key** if your application runs on Android devices.*
4. My Question is I have developed an offline app which runs on android phone. So which key should I prefer? Also if anyone has done this push notification stuff then please share whole procedure in simple words.It will be great help.

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create `server key` and search on __Google__  for detail steps....

Comment: Thanks for quick reply:) But then what the android key for?

Comment: `android key` is for Google maps and other stuff.

Comment: One more question, What should I enter in SERVER IP ADDRESSES edittext?

Comment: If you want to generate GCM Msg from your specific server then app IP.

Comment: Most tutorials saying to leave it blank, Do you think it is secure way? Sorry for so many questions!

Comment: Leave it blank it means your GCM is public.

Comment: ok Thank you very much for all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to create the **public server key** and shared it with your api developer which will used it for send push notification with using the Google Cloud Messaging.